# Location of network keys on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ethernet

In windows 7, is there a file / folder that stores the connected networks information. Where might I find the network information files for wired internet in the windows seven file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is where i was headed off to when my internet connection was failing.

HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\

The adapter in the parameters folder points to an interface directory.